# WKWebsiteDataStore doesn’t show cookie from setCookie in getAllCookies

Tags: ios, swift, cookies, webkit

In the following code, I’d expect the `print()` to log an array with a single cookie but it logs an empty array.

```
let websiteDataStore = WKWebsiteDataStore.nonPersistent()

websiteDataStore.httpCookieStore.setCookie(
    HTTPCookie(properties: [
        .domain: "example.com",
        .path: "/",
        .name: "MyCookieName",
        .value: "MyCookieValue",
        .secure: "TRUE",
        .expires: NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow: 31_556_926),
    ])!,
    completionHandler: { () in
        websiteDataStore.httpCookieStore.getAllCookies({ (cookies) in
            print(cookies)
        })
    }
)
```

Furthermore:

- When I use this `websiteDataStore` with a `WKWebView`, the server does not receive the cookie I set
- When I try adding a `WKHTTPCookieStoreObserver` the `cookiesDidChange` function is never fired

I’m testing in an iOS 17.2 emulator.

Why isn’t `setCookie()` adding a cookie?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I have `limitsNavigationsToAppBoundDomains` enabled and I was trying to set a cookie on localhost but I didn't have `<string>localhost</string>` in `<key>WKAppBoundDomains</key>` in my `Info.plist` file.

Adding it like this fixed things:

```
<key>WKAppBoundDomains</key>
<array>
    <string>localhost</string>
</array>
```

I was unclear if an exception was made for the `localhost` domain since other actions I would have expected to be limited (like adding scripts) worked fine.